# Determining Dimensions of Images in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, image

Simply, is it possible to somehow capture the dimensions (specifically, width and height) of an image using either the iPhone SDK or an iPhone SDK-compatible library/framework? Perhaps pull the dimensions from the EXIF metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Apple API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size) for `UIImage`, create a `UIImage` from your image data or file, then use the `size` property to get a `CGSize` structure representing the image's dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UIImage` name is `image`, you can get its size and then use the size to get the width and height like this:

```
CGSize mySize = [image size];
CGFloat imageWidth = mySize.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = mySize.height;
```